# wxWidgets Buttons Resize

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

Very new to widgets, but I've tried playing around on my own and can't seem to change the size of my button that I've created.

```
BasicFrame::BasicFrame(const wxChar *title, int xpos, int ypos, int width, int height)
    : wxFrame((wxFrame*)NULL, -1, title, wxPoint(xpos, ypos), wxSize(width, height))
{
    HelloWorld = new wxButton(this, BUTTON_Hello, _T("Hello World"),
                    // shows a button on this window
                    wxPoint(70,70), wxSize(30,30), wxBU_EXACTFIT); // with the text "hello World"
}
```

HelloWorld is a wxButton pointer. The button stays the same size as the window.

Why can't I change the size of my button with the section:

```
wxSize(30,30)
```

Thanks

Comment: Always use sizers unless you have a specific need. Also strongly recommending the wxFormBuilder software.

Answer (score 0):

As [explained in the documentation](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1.4/classwx_top_level_window.html#adfe7e3f4a32f3ed178968f64431bbfe0), if a top level window has exactly one child, it will be resized to fill in the entire window client area because this is almost always what you want to happen.

If you do *not* want this, you can work around it in various way, e.g. by creating another control (even an invisible one, such as `wxStaticText` with an empty label), overriding `Layout()` to not do anything in your `BasicFrame` or, usually the best, creating a `wxPanel` as the only frame child and then creating all the other controls as children of the panel.

In any cases, as already mentioned in a comment, using hard-coded sizes for the windows is almost always a bad idea. Using hard-coded sizes in pixels (and not dialog units or device-independent pixels) is *always* a bad idea.

Comment: maybe it make sense to use DIP when dealing with the position and size passed to wxWindow-based controls?